# How can I restrict the camera to stick within a background?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

In my game i have this 2048x2048 big background with a spaceship going up and down, back and forth like the old games there you face enemies coming in from the right, and you have the screen do dodge and fight them.

But how do I restrict the camera to the static background? The view is smaller then the background. Getting the bounds of the background is easy:

```
        Transform backgroundTransform = GameObject.Find("Background").transform;
        float minX = backgroundTransform.position.x - backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x / 2;
        float maxX = backgroundTransform.position.x + backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x / 2;
        float minY = backgroundTransform.position.y - backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y / 2;
        float maxY = backgroundTransform.position.y + backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y / 2;
```

But the camera does not have a "renderer" :) Any ideas?

Comment: is the camera following the spaceship?

Comment: You'll find the `Mathf.Clamp()` method useful: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Transform backgroundTransform = GameObject.Find("Background").transform;
float minX = backgroundTransform.position.x - backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x / 2;
float maxX = backgroundTransform.position.x + backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x / 2;
float minY = backgroundTransform.position.y - backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y / 2;
float maxY = backgroundTransform.position.y + backgroundTransform.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y / 2;
```

could literally be replaced with just:

```
Bounds backBounds = GameObject.Find("Background").GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds;
float minX = backBounds.min.x;
float maxX = backBounds.max.x;
float minY = backBounds.min.y;
float maxY = backBounds.max.y;
```

Anyway, here's some pseudo code (not tested)

```
Bounds backBounds = GameObject.Find("Background").GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds;
Camera cam;
float minX;
float maxX;
float minY;
float maxY;

if(cam.orthographic)
{
    minX = backBounds.min.x + (cam.orthographicSize * cam.aspect);
    maxX = backBounds.max.x - (cam.orthographicSize * cam.aspect);
    minY = backBounds.min.y + cam.orthographicSize;
    maxY = backBounds.max.y - cam.orthographicSize;
}
else
{
    float dist = Mathf.Abs(backBounds.center.z - cam.transform.position.z);
    float halfFrustumHeight = dist * Mathf.Tan(cam.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float halfFrustumWidth = frustumHeight * cam.aspect;

    minX = backBounds.min.x + halfFrustumWidth;
    maxX = backBounds.max.x - halfFrustumWidth;
    minY = backBounds.min.y + halfFrustumHeight;
    maxY = backBounds.max.y - halfFrustumHeight;
}
```